# Why the prohibition against blocking statements in FF synthesis?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, rtl

In most intros to Verilog, it's basically stated as a law that "blocking is for combinational and nonblocking is for sequential". That turns out to be a good rule of thumb because of how blocking and nonblocking statements work, but that's not a priori what blocking and nonblocking mean.

In Stuart Sutherland's *RTL Modeling with SystemVerilog*, he writes that one of the prohibitions enforced by synthesis compilers on `always` procedural blocks aimed at achieving FF synthesis is that

> (6) A variable assigned a value in a sequential logic procedure cannot have a mix of blocking and nonblocking assignments. For example, the reset branch cannot be modeled with a blocking assignment and the clocked branch modeled with a non- blocking assignment.

Thus, for instance, the code below for an active-low asynchronous-reset DFF would apparently not synthesize (correctly?):

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rstN)
  if (!rstN) q = 0; // NB the blocking statement made here
  else q <= d;
```

There is no problem from a simulation perspective given that the two branches of the `if-else` do not interact. Thus, my question is why doesn't synthesis accept/interpret this correctly? As far as I know, the point (6) above is also enforced by the `always_ff` block. Now that makes sense as a matter of good practice (since, as far as I know, `always_ff` etc. is meant to be for synthesis), but it still doesn't explain to me why in a general `always` block the above wouldn't work?

I follow that this is outside of what is a synthesizable construct but I am hoping to understand *why* that is. That is, I'm hoping to understand why the compiler would struggle with synthesizing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Verilog> Mixed blocking & non-blocking assignment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346718/verilog-mixed-blocking-non-blocking-assignment)

Comment: There's no benefit in allowing this. If this behaviour is desired, it can be realized with an additional variable, but in general it is not, and the diagnostic is more useful than having an output file.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I don't think it does, no. My question is not about understanding blocking vs nonblocking but rather understanding *why the design choice* of not allowing mixed statements.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you! @SimonRichter I wasn't sure if there was some deep reason related to hardware modelling that I was missing, rather than just a choice in order to simplify things from the compilation perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis software varies in what Verilog syntax is supported and what is not supported.  Some software may synthesize your code into the logic that you expect, while other software may generate errors and fail to synthesize the code.

I do not have access to the book, but it is reasonable to assume the author intends this to be a *guideline* for good coding style, rather than a claim that all synthesis tools will prohibit this syntax.

Following the coding style recommendation increases your chance of success: success that you will infer the intended synthesized logic, and success that the simulation will match pre- and post-synthesis.

Comment: Understood, thank you as always toolic! Linking this question too which is a related answer (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/700700/why-cant-you-mix-edge-signals-with-level-signals-in-systemverilog-for-synthesis/700702?noredirect=1#comment1865819_700702).

Comment: This answer is does not correctly answer the question. There are specific problems this coding style generates for simulation

Comment: This answer does correctly answer the question.  There are no incorrect statements in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general synthesis tools don't care if you use blocking or nonblocking assignments to variables unless you try to read the same variable after writing to it in the same block. That determines if you need to use the old or new value of the variable. There are no problems doing multiple assignments to the same variable is the same always block as long as you use the same kind of assigment--last write wins.

However there are problems mixing blocking and nonblocking assignments to the same variable that will create functional problems.

The original example mixes synchronous and asynchronous in a single `always` block. If the `posedge clk` occurs first, a non-blocking assignment to `q` gets scheduled. But then a `negedge rstN` occurs the same time (a race in the same event region), `q` is set to 0. However the nonblocking assignment to q is still pending. The asynchronous reset gets ignored.

This is an unfortunate consequence of current synthesis tool modeling styles requiring a variables be assigned from only a single `always` block. Verilog was originally designed to handle this with two seperate `always blocks.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin // synchronous behavior 
   q <= d;
end
always @(rstN) begin asynchronous behavior
   if (!rstN)
      assign q = 0;  // procedural continuous assignment
   else
      deassign q;
end
```

A number of synthesis tools used to support this modeling style, but they are now obsolete.

Another problem is much simpler to describe

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
   flag <=0; // default value
   if (condition)
      flag = 1; // will be overwritten by NBA
end
```

This is syntactically legal, but will never behave correctly. Synthesis tools flag this as an error because it cannot set the flag to 1. Both assignments should be nonblocking.

Comment: Can an always block be entered twice in the Active region of the same simulation time \$t\$? If so, how does changing the reset to a nonblocking assignment fix this? Won't whichever of `posedge clk` and `negedge rstN` which happens list "win out" in this case? Perhaps I am not understanding.

Comment: Yes, an `always` block can be entered for each event in the sensitivity list. When the reset comes first, the `if` statement prevents overwriting. But the overwriting problem comes in when the `clk` comes first.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm really struggling to follow, but can you explain that a bit more? If the reset comes first then won't we initially set `q = 0`, but then since we enter again beccause of `clk` won't we get `q = d` by the end of the nonblocking active region?

Comment: If reset goes low first (active low), then it doesn't matter which assignment (blocking or nonblocking) you use when the clock rises because only the `q` assignment to 0 statement gets executed. It might help if you made a table of the 8 possible scenarios with clk or reset coming first to gether with the 4 combinations of assignments to q=0/q=d., q=0/q<=d, etc.

Comment: Ah I follow now. I missed that (of course) when `rstN` goes low, it remains there (and so is low for when we enter the always block because of `Clk` too). Thanks again!